# Selenium python clicking on button trouble

Tags: python, selenium

I new with selenium, and I am having particular trouble with this button I've tried(submit and click):

```
driver.find_element_by_id("btn").clcik;
driver.find_element_by_class_name("eh_prev_img").click
```

The two above find the element though for some reason the click does not work, the html code is below:

```
<div id="btn">
<a class="eh_prev_img" title="red"> 
</a> 
</div>
```

the button is supposed to bring up a pop up

Comment: Your first line won't work even if you change `clcik` to `click()` as you are trying to click on a div. The second line should work if you will change `click` to `click()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try .click()

Look for more examples at http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/faq.html